# Как выполнить Javascript код?

Tags: javascript

*я почти не знаю javascript*

Есть функция:

```
function getSequence(str1, str2) 
{    
    const arr1 = str1.split(',');    
    const arr2 = str2.split(',');    
    let i = 0;    
    let arr3 = arr2.map(n = i = arr2[i]);    
    let result = '%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s';    
    arr3.forEach(n = {        
        result = result.replace('%s', arr1[n]);    
    });    
     return result;
}
```

нужно как то ее выполнить и получить ответ. Как это можно сделать?

```
print(getSequence("строка", "строка"));
```

Comment: где это можно выполнить, есть какие то компиляторы?
Можно ведь записать в блокнот и поменять расширение файла txt на js?

Comment: У меня не компилируется, может это ошибки в коде?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, **что вы хотите получить** в результате и т. д. **Приведите пример**, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Мне просто нужно выполнить этот код и я не знаю как

Comment: никак, в коде синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: Ну а что вы пробуете, и что не получается?

Comment: Покажите их, пожалуйста

Comment: `n = i = arr2[i]`, `arr3.forEach(n = {`

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Comment: Ответьте еще, где можно проверить работу, где скомпилировать?

Comment: @Anamnian [V8 never included anything like an interpreter, and most major JS engines feature JIT compilers by now. Thus, saying that "JavaScript is interpreted" is obviously wrong (or maybe your definition of interpreter/compiler is)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623813/is-javascript-compiled-or-an-interpreted-language#comment12245421_9623845) а так же: [Is JavaScript interpreted by design?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/138521)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял - console.log(getSequence("строка", "строка"));

После, подключите ваш JS скрипт к html-файлу методом скрипта:

```
 <script src="index.js"></script>
```

И запустите html файл в браузере. 
Там нажмите `f12` и прейдите во вкладку `console`. Там и будет ждать вывод

Answer (score 0):

Например, здесь. Только я не знаю, чтобы джаваскрипт компилировался. Он исполняется в браузере без компиляции.
http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output

Comment: Вернее будет сказать что JS является интерпретируемым языком.  
    Интерпретатор — программа (разновидность транслятора), выполняющая интерпретацию.

Интерпретация — построчный анализ, обработка и выполнение исходного кода программы или запроса (в отличие от компиляции, где весь текст программы, перед запуском, анализируется и транслируется в машинный или байт-код, без её выполнения).

Comment: [V8 never included anything like an interpreter, and most major JS engines feature JIT compilers by now. Thus, saying that "JavaScript is interpreted" is obviously wrong (or maybe your definition of interpreter/compiler is)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623813/is-javascript-compiled-or-an-interpreted-language#comment12245421_9623845) а так же: [Is JavaScript interpreted by design?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/138521)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ссылку, я был не прав.